# how to set up Windows Server 2008 perfmon alert

Tags: windows-server-2008, perfmon

in Windows 2008, how can I set up perfmon alerts to execute some scheduled task or batch file? I found examples for Windows 2003, but not 2008.

for example, I want to execute a task if free space on C drive goes below 10%. how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Reliability and Performance tool to monitor the "% Disk Free" counter. Create a Data Collector Set and set it to run the task when it falls below your threshold using the "Alert Task" tab in the Data Collector Properties.